# Why did Sirius attack Gryffindor tower the second time?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

When Sirius goes into the boys dormitory and Ron wakes up, Peter/Scabbers already faked his death and Sirius knows it. so what did he attack the second time for?

here's the timeline:

in POA chapter 12 Wormtail fakes his death:

> Harry looked down at the sheet Ron was holding. There was something red on it. Something that looked horribly like-
> 　　"BLOOD!" Ron yelled into the stunned silence. "HE'S GONE!

We later know that Crookshanks informed Sirius about Scabbers faking his death-

> "This cat -- Crookshanks, did you call him? -- told me Peter had left blood on the sheets....

However, in chapter 13, after Peter fakes his death and Black is informed, Sirius breaks into Gryffindor tower:

> "PROFESSOR, I WOKE UP, AND SIRIUS BLACK WAS STANDING OVER ME, HOLDING A KNIFE!"

So what did Sirius hope to find there, when he knew perfectly well Peter wasn't there?

More than that, Sirius presents the story not in the chronological order:

> "He tried to bring Peter to me, but couldn't... so he stole the passwords into Gryffindor Tower for me.... As I understand it, he took them from a boy's bedside table...."
> 　　Harry's brain seemed to be sagging under the weight of what he was hearing. It was absurd... and yet...
> 　　"But Peter got wind of what was going on and ran for it." croaked Black. "This cat -- Crookshanks, did you call him? -- **told me Peter had left blood on the sheets**.... I supposed he bit himself... Well, faking his own death had worked once."

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I can only think of two possible explanations (and I don't particularly like either of them): 1. He thought that Peter would still be hiding in the Gryffindor dormitory after faking his death. 2. Crookshanks told him about Peter attempting to fake his death *after* Sirius broke in the second time.

Comment: Maybe Crookshanks told Sirius after the break-in took place?

Comment: Crookshanks stole the passwords before the break-in and gave them to Sirius, at the time he knew Sirius was using the passwords to get  Scabbers in Gryffindor tower and knew Scabbers faked his death and isn't in Gryffindor tower, so it seems odd he won't point out to Sirius that Scabbers isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sirius likely didn’t know that Peter had faked his death prior to the attack. Consider that immediately before Ron found  the bloody sheets the following occurred:

> They turned into the corridor to Gryffindor Tower and saw Neville Longbottom, pleading with Sir Cadogan, who seemed to be refusing him entrance.
>
> “I wrote them down!” Neville was saying tearfully. “But I must’ve dropped them somewhere!”

This tells us that Crookshanks had already stolen the passwords. Yet Peter’s fake death could only have occurred in the previous few hours, as otherwise Ron would have already seen the  bloody sheets on his previous time in the dormitory.

It is thus possible that Crookshanks gave the Passwords to Sirius before Peter faked his death.

Comment: Re-reading that part of the book, this seems more likely than I first thought. There only seems to be a few days at most between Scabbers going missing (presumed dead) and Sirius breaking in. Given how angry and upset Ron was, it's likely that Hermione would have kept Crookshanks in her dormitory, preventing Sirius from finding out that Peter had fled.

Comment: it's a good answer but I still don't get why Sirius tells the story not-in-order. he first says he got the passwords and broke in, and because of that Peter faked his own death. did he just get confused?

Comment: @MBEllis possibly it's because that's the order that Sirus becames aware of it. He breaks in, and then learns scanners is missing. So he repeats that order.

Comment: Sirius is explaining his actions, so what he knew at the point he made his decisions is more important than the actual order of events.

Comment: makes sense. thanks. 